# how can I extract element in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a np.where line in my code that outputs

```
array('ML',
      dtype='<U2')
```

how can I extract the 'ML' part please?

Thank you

Comment: Use index notation. arr[0]

Comment: my actual output is allHoldingsFund['x'].iloc[i]= array('ML', dtype ='<U2')  . how do you suggest i use the notation  arr[] in this context  to extract 'ML'? Thank you

Comment: can someone help please?